# Examine if the function is injective, how to interpret the result of proof

Tags: functions

I am supposed to examine if the following function is injective or not. $$h:\!R \mapsto \!R \mid h(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}$$

I have begun by assuming it is injective and trying to prove that by a contrapostive; that is assume $h(x_{1})=h(x_{2}) \implies x_{1}=x_{2}$. However, upon doing thus I find the following:

$$x_{1}x_{2}=x_{1}x_{2}$$

I am not sure how I shall interpret this result, that is if the function is injective or not. Am I doing something wrong or shall I use a different method for proving/disproving injectivity? I am quite new to these kinds of problems.

Comment: The domain of $h$ can't possibly be $\Bbb R$.

Comment: You can't interpret the result. You've reached a step which is true regardless of what value $x_1, x_2, h(x_1), h(x_2)$ are. Knowing this undeniable and completely unconditional fact cannot tell you anything specific about $x_1$ and $x_2$, let alone that they're equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\dfrac{1-\sqrt{a}}{1+\sqrt{a}} &=& \dfrac{1-\sqrt{b}}{1+\sqrt{b}} \\
\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{a}} - 1 &=& \dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{b}} - 1 \\
\dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{a}} &=& \dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{b}} \\
1+\sqrt{a} &=& 1+\sqrt{b} \\
\sqrt{a} &=& \sqrt{b} \\
a &=& b
\end{array}$$

---

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\dfrac{1-\sqrt{a}}{1+\sqrt{a}} &=& \dfrac{1-\sqrt{b}}{1+\sqrt{b}} \\
(1-\sqrt{a})(1+\sqrt{b}) &=& (1-\sqrt{b})(1+\sqrt{a}) \\
1-\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{ab} &=& 1+\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{ab} \\
-\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b} &=& \sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} \\
-2\sqrt{a} &=& -2\sqrt{b} \\
\sqrt{a} &=& \sqrt{b} \\
a &=& b \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: I think this would be a far better answer if it addressed the question of "how to interpret the result" that the OP poses.

Comment: @user296602 I have no idea how OP reached that step. The standard interpretation of that result is that the steps are wrong.

Comment: Right, so maybe wait for the OP to clarify what they *do* understand and how they got there. (Or include the comment about your interpretation in your answer...).

Comment: I did cross multiplication in the first step, that must the wrong part?

Comment: @Sindbad Included a solution with cross multiplication.

Comment: @KennyLau I see, my algebra was wrong twice... I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

$h(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}=\frac {2}{1+\sqrt{x}} -1$

Because $\sqrt{x}$ is strictly increasing it follows that $h(x)$ is strictly decreasing, therefore it is injective.